How to make a multi-level context menu scrollable?
I'm trying to build a (left-click) context menu with HTML+CSS.
It should be multi-level (hovering over some items shows a submenu next to the item).
Each level should also be scrollable when it contains too many items (e.g. more than 30).
I know that a pdf with JS-backend can do what I want (though with buttons at top and bottom, I would prefer the scroll wheel to (also) work).
multi-level context menu in pdf (Acrobat)

I've tried using overflow-y: auto, but it always seems to hide overflow in x as well (even with overflow-x: visible), and I'm not a big fan of the scrollbars themselves either.
Here is an MWE of what I have (HTML) - I'm not opposed to using javascript here, but would like to avoid it if possible.


.context-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.context-menu * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.context-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.context-menu li {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  padding-right: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}

.context-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.context-menu li .icon_span {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.context-menu li .sub_span {
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
}

.context-menu li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.context-menu li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.context-menu li.separator {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

.context-menu li.separator:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.context-menu.orient-left>ul ul {
  left: unset;
  right: 100%;
}

.context-menu.orient-top>ul ul {
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
}

.context-menu li[disabled=""] {
  color: #777;
  cursor: default;
}

.context-menu li[disabled=""]:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}
<div class="context-menu" style="left: 10px; top: 18px;">
  <ul>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 1</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 2</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 3</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
    <li class="separator"></li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Menu Option</span><span class="sub_span">›</span>
      <ul>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 1</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 2</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 3</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 4</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 5</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 6</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 7</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 8</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 9</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 10</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 11</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 12</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 13</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 14</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 15</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 16</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 17</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 18</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 19</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 20</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 21</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 22</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 23</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 24</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 25</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 26</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 27</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 28</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 29</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="separator"></li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 4</span><span class="sub_span"> </span> </li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 5</span><span class="sub_span"> </span> </li>
  </ul>
</div>




You have to use script to open the submenu items through the click of the parent div and have to import jquery to do that, the following code helps to open the submenu of the parent


 // Sub menu js
    $('.context-menu ul li.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('sub-open')) {
            $('.navbar ul.navbar-nav>li.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('sub-open');
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('sub-open');
    });
    $(".context-menu ul li.menu-item-has-children").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
.context-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
}

.context-menu * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.context-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.context-menu li {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  padding-right: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}

.context-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.context-menu li .icon_span {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.context-menu li .sub_span {
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
}

.context-menu ul li.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.context-menu li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.context-menu li.separator {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

.context-menu li.separator:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.context-menu.orient-left>ul ul {
  left: unset;
  right: 100%;
}

.context-menu.orient-top>ul ul {
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
}

.context-menu li[disabled=""] {
  color: #777;
  cursor: default;
}

.context-menu li[disabled=""]:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}
.context-menu ul li.menu-item-has-children.sub-open > ul.sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
}
.context-menu ul li.menu-item-has-children {
    padding-right: 0;
}
<div class="context-menu" style="left: 10px; top: 18px;">
  <ul>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 1</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 2</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 3</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
    <li class="separator"></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Menu Option</span><span class="sub_span">›</span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 1</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 2</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 3</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 4</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 5</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 6</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 7</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 8</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 9</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 10</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 11</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 12</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 13</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 14</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 15</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 16</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 17</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 18</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 19</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 20</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 21</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 22</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 23</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 24</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 25</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 26</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 27</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 28</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
        <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Foo 29</span><span class="sub_span"></span> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="separator"></li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 4</span><span class="sub_span"> </span> </li>
    <li> <span class="icon_span"></span><span class="text_span">Option 5</span><span class="sub_span"> </span> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Thank you for your answer. There's still an issue with a scrollbar on the first level taking the second into account, but I suppose I should give up trying to do it without javascript. I can work from this.
